# Foundation: How to stack columns in responsive layout?

Tags: layout, grid, zurb-foundation

Trying to figure out how to a do a responsive layout using Foundation. I am new to this and familiar with the ability to use push and pull but I am struggling trying to figure out how to stack items in a single row.

Visual: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCVPO.png

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="small-12 large-? columns"> A </div>
 <div class="small-12 large-? columns"> B </div>
 <div class="small-12 large-? columns"> C </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i think your code (according to your image) would be like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-6 large-push-6 columns">A</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 large-6 large-pull-6 columns">B</div>
            <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could check "Advanced" & "Source Ordering" sections in http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. This solution sort of works but the heights are not lining up, A and B are the same size and C seems to sit below them. The Height of B seems to resize with the content of A.